# SPA Routing Without JS Using @document

Tags: javascript, html, css, routes, single-page-application

Does the CSS (Level 4) `@document` rule support URLs containing the `#` symbol or include URL query parameters?

[For those not familiar](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-document-rule/)

I know that this is not supported in any browsers except for Firefox with the `@-moz-document` prefix right now. If this *does* end up making its way into other browsers, this seems like it might finally allow for CSS only SPA routing (even with JS disabled). If anyone has not tested this, I will experiment this weekend.

For example

```
@document url("https://www.site.example/#/page-1/") {
    .page-2 {
        display: none;
    }
}

@document url("https://www.site.example/#/page-2/") {
    .page-1 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I think that a build tool might be able to be created for CSS fallback for React / Gatsby or other static generated sites that would otherwise result in a poor experience due to lack of routing, even with a `<noscript>` fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, tested this. It does not work due to @document not updating on URL change in the same way that @media continuously checks for screen size change. If it does make its way into the spec, I hope that there is a possibility of this behavior changing.

`@document` *does* see the `#` and `?` in the URL, but requires a refresh to see the effects at this time.